# How to get the last unique transactions from a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that contains the following fields: `agentId`, `postBalance`, `preBalance`, etc. I want to fetch the last unique record for an agent that contains the field stated earlier based on a date filter.

```js
db.transaction.find(
  {
    "createdAt" : {
      "$gte": ISODate("2022-09-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "$lt": ISODate("2022-09-02T00:00:00Z")
    }
  },
  {
    “agentId”: 1,
    “walletBalance”: 1
  }
)
```

The query above returns duplicate values and not the latest one. How best do I optimise this query. I am using Mongo Compass so I don't mind any query that comes in that format. I have read up on `$last, $natural` but they don't seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add sort by "createdAt" and limit of 1, or just using findOne method with same sort?